Dicebear avatar converter in React Native isn't converting svg to png
I am using dicebear in my React Native project and have already generated an avatar that displays as an svg (using react-native-svg). However, I would like to generate that avatar as a png and for that I'll need a png data uri. I'm trying to do that using dicebear convert, but it is returning an error.
This is my convert svg to png function:
import { createAvatar } from '@dicebear/core';
import { avataaars } from '@dicebear/collection';
import { toPng } from '@dicebear/converter';

const generateAvatarPNG = async () => {
        try {
            const svg = createAvatar(avataaars, {
                seed: 'John Doe',
                // ... other options
            }).toString();

            const png = toPng(svg, {
                // ... options
            });

            const dataUri = await png.toDataUri(); 

            console.log(png);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }

I tried following the documentation and was expecting a string that would be the png data uri.
https://www.dicebear.com/how-to-use/js-library/converter/#todatauri
